# How to solve this program using enumerate?

Tags: python, file, record, enumerate

```
  f=open('Student.dat','r+') # opens Student.dat file
  roll1=input("Enter roll to be found") # to find a record in a list using a roll no
  rec=f.readlines()
  for i,lst in enumerate(rec):
    if lst == roll1:
        print rec[i]
```

Is this the proper way to use enumerate?? or should i use another loop within??

what i mean is: 
   i have a list like [1,apple.,2,mango] now using enumerate i want to print    the record 2.,mango completely after searching for it using the roll no. if roll==2 then print the record.

Comment: You have a `list` where every other item is an integer representing the index?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use like this:

```
f=open('Student.dat','r+') # opens Student.dat file
roll1= int(input("Enter roll to be found")) # need to use int to convert to integer type
for i,lst in enumerate(f):
    if i == roll1:
        print lst
```

Comment: its not working...i am not getting any output